# How to know the exact time a user submitted a form

Tags: php, javascript, security, latency

We're building an online test with individually timed questions. The questions are a series of forms which the users must complete within a pre-determined number of seconds. Although the users will see a javascript ticking clock on each question, the actual *enforcement* of the time limit must happen server-side (otherwise it would be very easy for the user to disable/modify the time limit). However, we are concerned that network latency will unfairly penalize users who submit their answer close to the end of the time limit, close enough for latency to make their response over the time limit.

The sloppy solution seems to be to just allow a few second "grace period" when we check the duration as the answer is received at the server, but this is kind of lame. **Is there a secure way to determine precisely when the user clicked "Submit".**

If it matters, the web app is written in PHP.

Comment: As you note, you cannot trust information you get from the client.

Comment: And you certainly can't trust timers from the clientside, or rely on a certain upload speed from the user.

Comment: You could get with JS the time when the submit button is clicked and send that information in a hidden input with the user answer, but that could be hackeable too. I would use your first approch, use always server time, but with a grace period of 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: Not only hackable, a user with a computer clock that's off a few minutes or hours is rather common, and it's probably the data you least can trust from the clientside.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually had to deal with this problem before. What we ended up doing, is marking the time that the request for the page was made, and using a javascript ajax request (on load) from the browser to determine the round-trip time. Averaged out it ends up representing their network latency / computer speed, pretty well.

Obviously if it gets to anything over 15-20 seconds you have a bigger problem, but the most we saw was 3-4 seconds.

You can then use this in a "fairness" evaluation of how much time it actually took them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you capture the time it takes until you receive the response from the AJAX request to determine the latency. Is that right? So basically you store the time(1), send the page, trigger the ajax call as soon as the page loads, capture the time(2) when that ajax call is received. And so time(2) - time(1) is the latency. This makes sense, but is it reasonable to expect the latency to stay consistent? Some of the questions on our test might be as long as 10 minutes. What are the odds that the latency will change during that time?

Comment: No, the latency will change (especially on slower computers) thats why you have to average it out. You can keep a persistent callback every 3-4 seconds on a timer, and continue to average it out over the course of the question, you just have to make sure that the no-cache is set on the responding page so IE doesn't just cache the results and stop responding to you.
I'd recommend that you send the pieces that they fill out as they fill it out, that way the data is always changing. And worst case you can take the last answer in the event that the timer runs out when they submit it.

Comment: You'll also be able to tell if a user disconnected in the middle of a question, which is always useful for determining re-take eligability.

Comment: When I first did this I tried to do a weighted scale on the average so that the initial load time had more impact, because the submit is usually closer to the initial load time. But I was never able to find the right weight, the general average seemed to work better.